# Iterate over JSON data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

I am working on some trains' open data feed and getting some JSON as a response from a server. I parse this JSON into a data variable and display it as seen below. However, I cannot find a way to iterate over the response to be able to manipulate each message. I want to iterate over each message and then use the data for a record in a SQL database. I cannot get to the point of accessing any individual message data.

How can I create a loop to iterate over each message and extract it's data?

```
[
  {
    SF_MSG: {
      time: '1666370311000',
      area_id: 'TD',
      address: '0C',
      msg_type: 'SF',
      data: '1F'
    }
  },
  {
    CA_MSG: {
      to: '4333',
      time: '1666370311000',
      area_id: 'WO',
      msg_type: 'CA',
      from: '4331',
      descr: '2K60'
    }
  }, ...
]
```

Edit: using `data.forEach(function(message)` produces an output of the structure:

`{ CA_MSG: { to: '6021', time: '1666372120000', area_id: 'CY', msg_type: 'CA', from: 'STIN', descr: '2Y73' } }`
, however, how do I query this inner object, the names of the objects will differ depending on message type if this matters?

Comment: pls show us what you have tried so far

Comment: `data.forEach(function(message) { ... });` — is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Did you get as far as: `for (let message of JSON.parse(myJson))` ?

Comment: I tried using for each, to get each input, my query was about how do I query the inner object resulting from the for each?

Comment: `Object.values(message)[0].area_id` for example.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
data = JSON.parse(yourJSONdata)
data.map((o, i)=>{
//o is the object, i is the index
// do your processing here
```

then at the end do

```
data[i]=processedobject
})
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `.map()` if your code ignores the returned array; `.forEach()` is more appropriate.

Comment: ah people keep saying that, but when I use forEach they say to use map for similar cases

Comment: those people are wrong.